# Spinner inside the button in Angular

Tags: angular

I have a button `Update`.After entering the Inputs,When user enters `Update`,button should show `Updating` instead of `Update`.

But I need spinner inside this button before `Updating`.

I surfed in the net,there is a option of `mat-progress-buttons`.The problem is,the spinner is in the middle of the button without showing any text like `Updating`.

But I need a spinner before `Updating`.That spinner should be also inside the button.

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Add a Stackblitz with your code, it will help understanding what's wrong

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can create a reusable button child component like this:

**[Working Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-uvxs7c?embed=1&file=src/app/app.component.ts)**

child.html

```
<button [disabled]="disabled" class="btn rounded-btn btn-primary submitBtn"  [style.pointer-events]="spin?'none':''"  id=submitBtn>
   <i class="fa fa-spinner fa-spin " *ngIf="spin"> </i>
  &nbsp; {{spin? 'Updating' : 'Update'}} &nbsp;
</button>
```

child.ts

```
@Component({
  selector: 'save-button',
  templateUrl: './save-button.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./save-button.component.css']
})
export class SaveButtonComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor() { }
  @Input() disabled: boolean;
  @Input() spin: boolean

  ngOnInit() {
  }

}
```

parent.html

```
<save-button  (click)="onSubmit()" [spin]="spinLoader"></save-button>
```

parent.ts

```
spinLoader= false;

  onSubmit() {
    this.spinLoader = true
  }
```

Comment: I have one doubt.why we should use two .ts? why We cannot done using one html and ts file>

Comment: For reusability, this can be done in the same file too, in that case you have to code the same thing wherever this feature is needed

Answer (score 0):

To complement, you can add the Awesome font in angular following [these instructions](https://blog.logrocket.com/how-to-add-font-awesome-angular-project/).

And more information in the [package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@fortawesome/angular-fontawesome)

**component.html**

```
<button
    [disabled]="disabled"
    [style.pointer-events]="spin?'none':''"
    (click)="spin=true"
    type="submit">
    <fa-icon [icon]="faSpinner" [spin]="true" *ngIf="spin"></fa-icon>
</button>
```

**component.ts**

```
import {Component, Input, SimpleChanges} from '@angular/core';
import { faSpinner } from '@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons';

@Component({
    selector: 'app-save-button',
    templateUrl: './save-button.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./save-button.component.scss']
})
export class SaveButtonComponent{
    @Input() label = '';
    @Input() disabled = false;
    spin = false;
    faSpinner = faSpinner;

    ngOnChanges(changes: SimpleChanges) {
        if('disabled' in changes && changes.disabled)
            this.spin=false;
    }
}
```

**app.module.ts**

```
    import {FontAwesomeModule} from '@fortawesome/angular-fontawesome';
...
imports: [...FontAwesomeModule...
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).